# Output of program for user input giving different length for consonant with user input. input 1 --> abc input2--> 'abc'

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-length

""" why this 4  in second user input as 'abc'.ii know that it is counting quotes as python will take input 'abc' as " ' abc ' " hence counting 5 as length how to remove this issue for getting correct answer like other input as shown above n below"""

## to get count vowels n consonants

```
 def get_count(words):
    words=str(input('Enter:')).lower()
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    v_count = 0
    c_count = 0
    for letter in words:
        if letter in vowels:
            v_count += 1
        else:
            c_count+=1
    print("vowel : {}".format(v_count), "consonant: {}".format(c_count))
get_count(input)

Result:

Enter:aBc
vowel : 1 consonant: 2
Enter:'abc'
vowel : 1 consonant: 4-  ??? why
```

> Blockquote

```
Enter:abc
vowel : 1 consonant: 2
```

Comment: and.., *what is the question*?

Comment: so  words=str(input('Enter:')).lower() now when i input - abc len operation gives length is 3 which fine, but when  i enter 'abc' len operation gives length 5 . why ?? this i throwing error in my program

Comment: Hi All i hope I am able to convey correct:- x=len(abc) is 3 while x=len('abc') is 5 when user input is used in program ? how to over comthis issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long answer: So your string is **'abc'** which is 5 characters long.
python is checking:

- if first character **'** is in vowels and it is
  not so consonant = 0+1
- second character is **a**, it is in vowels so
  vowels = 0+1
- third **b** which is not in vowels, so consonant = 1+1
  (which is 2 now)
- fourth **c** which is not in vowels, so consonant =
  2+1 (which is 3 now)
- fifth character is **'** which is not in vowels,
  so consonant = 3+1 (which is 4 now)

so in the end we get: vowel : 1 consonant: 4

Short answer: your input is considered as a five character long string, and your script iterates over each element including single quotations.

Comment: andriyze -- Your explanation is really awesome. I was confused with that fact that python was counting " ' " also part of character

Answer (score 0):

You should judge whether the character is in alphabet first.

```
def get_count(words):
    words=str(input('Enter:'))
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    v_count = 0
    c_count = 0
    for char in words:
        if char.isalpha():
            if char.lower() in vowels:
                v_count += 1
            else:
                c_count+=1
    print("vowel : {}".format(v_count), "consonant: {}".format(c_count))
get_count(input)
```

Comment: Thank you Tisoga. This addition character alphabet thing works.